# I am always getting fingerprint not verified

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fingerprint

Anytime I scan a fingerprint for verification I get the message "Fingerprint not verified" even though I have already enrolled that fingerprint into the database. Here is the code for capture when the form loads

Here is the code for capture when the form loads

```vb
Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Init()
    StartCapture()

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sql As String
    conn.ConnectionString = "**** "
    conn.Open()
    sql = ("SELECT * FROM new_case_file")
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While (rdr.Read())
        Dim MemStream As IO.MemoryStream
        Dim fpBytes As Byte()

        fpBytes = rdr("FingerPrint")
        MemStream = New IO.MemoryStream(fpBytes)

        Dim templa8 As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template()
        templa8.DeSerialize(MemStream)
        Dim serializedTemplate As Byte() = MemStream.ToArray

        Dim tmpObj As New AppData
        Dim FPList As List(Of AppData) = New List(Of AppData)
        'tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString()
        'tmpObj.Template = templa8
        'FPList.Add(tmpObj)
    End While
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Here is the code for verification. When l click on the button it should verify, because l called the sub `verifyControl_Commplete` in the button click sub.

```vb
Private Sub verifyControl_OnComplete(ByVal Control As Object, ByVal FeatureSet As DPFP.FeatureSet, ByRef EventHandlerStatus As
DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus) Handles verifyControl.OnComplete


    Dim printFound As Boolean = False
    'Dim printFound As Boolean = True
    'Dim printFound As Boolean = False
    Dim VerifiedFPData = New AppData
    Dim FPList As List(Of AppData) = New List(Of AppData)
    Try

        For Each FPData As AppData In FPList
            Dim tmplateData As New DPFP.Template
            'tmplateData = FPData.Template
            Dim compareTo As New DPFP.FeatureSet
            compareTo = FeatureSet

            Dim ver As New DPFP.Verification.Verification()
            Dim res As New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()

            If Not tmplateData Is Nothing Then
                ver.Verify(FeatureSet, tmplateData, res)

                If res.Verified Then
                    EventHandlerStatus = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Success
                    printFound = True
                    VerifiedFPData = FPData

                    Exit For

                End If
            End If

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try


    If printFound Then
        MsgBox("Verified")
    Else
        EventHandlerStatus = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Failure

        MsgBox("Not Verified")
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnverifyfp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnverifyfp.Click
    verifyControl_OnComplete(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

This is the code l used in saving the fingerprint

```vb
Dim fingerprintData As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
Enroller.Template.Serialize(fingerprintData)
Dim serializedTemplate As Byte() = fingerprintData.ToArray()
Dim bytes() As Byte = serializedTemplate
```

Comment: Please format your code, its not easy to follow. Also questions seeking debugging help is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
'THIS NEEDS TO BE AT THE CLASS-LEVEL, AS A MEMBER
Private FPList As New List(Of AppData)

Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e AsSystem.EventArgs) 
                                                           Handles MyBase.Load    
    Init()
    StartCapture()

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM new_case_file"
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("**** "), _
          cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

        conn.Open()
        Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            FPList.Clear()
            While (rdr.Read())
                Dim tmpObj As New AppData
                tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString()

                Dim fpBytes As Byte() = rdr("FingerPrint")
                Using MemStream As New IO.MemoryStream(fpBytes)

                    Dim templa8 As New DPFP.Template()
                    templa8.DeSerialize(MemStream)
                End Using
                tmpObj.Template = templa8

                FPList.Add(tmpObj)
            End While
            rdr.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

And now other code later can use that same `FPList` variable. If you find yourself writing `New List(Of AppData)` anywhere else, you're doing something wrong.

The `AppData` class should look something like this:

```vb
Public Class AppData
    Public Property No As String   
    Public Property Template As DFFP.Template
End Class
```

And finally, the verify code:

```vb
Private Sub verifyControl_OnComplete(ByVal Control As Object, ByVal FeatureSet As DPFP.FeatureSet, 
                                     ByRef EventHandlerStatus As DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus)
     Handles verifyControl.OnComplete

    Try

        Dim ver As New DPFP.Verification.Verification()
        Dim res As New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()

        For Each FPData As AppData In FPList
            If FPData.Template Is Nothing Then Continue

            ver.Verify(FeatureSet, FPData.Template, res)
            If res.Verified Then
                EventHandlerStatus = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Success
                MsgBox("Verified")
                Return
            End If

        Next FPDAta

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try

    EventHandlerStatus = DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus.Failure
    MsgBox("Not Verified")
End Sub
```

Again... we don't have access to your API documentation, test data, or equipment. That means we're blind trying to help you here. There's probably some things wrong with this, and you'll have to be able to troubleshoot and debug.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. l tried your code, it gave an error on this line Using (rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) rdr  is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Can you help?

Comment: That line declares rdr. Are you confident the code copied correctly

Comment: Yes, copied and pasted.

Comment: Oh... just remove the parentheses around the outside. Too much time writing C# for me :/

Comment: When the brackets are on as in Using (rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()),
I get the error rdr "is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level and also As gives the error ')' is expected. When l remove the brackets as you suggested, I get error on error on this line tmpObj.No = rdr("No").ToString() 'No' is not a member of the project.Form.AppData, also tmpObj.Template = templa8 gives an error 'Template is not a member of the project.Form.AppData. I'm new to VB.Net and programming in general. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You built the  `AppData` class. Use the members your put there.

Comment: Public Class AppData
         Private FPList As New List(Of AppData)
End Class.   This is what l did, if you can point me in the right direction. I'm a newbie